# Compare two arrays of hashes and calculate position changes

Tags: ruby

I am trying to take two arrays of hashes that contain the position for IDs, and return the position change. The data are from charts scraped on different dates.

If chart 1 from 2018-01-01 contains:

```
[
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}, 
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"}
]
```

and chart 2 from 2018-01-07 contains:

```
[
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"},
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}
]
```

how do I produce a result that will show the position change?

```
[
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001", :change=>0}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003", :change=>1},
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002", :change=>-1} 
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicated `id`s:

```
in1 = [
   {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"},   
   {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"},   
   {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"}  
]  
in2 = [
   {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"},   
   {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"},  
   {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}  
]  
[in1, in2].map do |a|
  a.group_by { |h| h[:id] }
end.reduce do |h1, h2|
  h1.merge(h2) do |k, v1, v2|
    v2.first.merge(change: v1.first[:position] - v2.first[:position])
  end
end.values.sort_by { |h| h[:position] }
#⇒ [{:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001", :change=>0},
#   {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003", :change=>1},
#   {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002", :change=>-1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chart1 = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}, 
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"}
]

chart2 = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"},
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}
]

h = chart1.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(g,i),h| h[g[:id]] = i }
  #=> {"GBMMV1800001"=>0, "GBMMV1800002"=>1, "GBMMV1800003"=>2}
chart2.each_with_index.map { |g,i| g.merge(change: h[g[:id]] - i) }
  #=> [{:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001", :change=>0},
  #    {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003", :change=>1},
  #    {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002", :change=>-1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
h1 = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}, 
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"}
]

h2 = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"},
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}
]
```

I want to get a map of `{ id => [position1, position2] }`.

To start out I iterate through h1 to get its positions

```
vals = {}
h1.each do |val|
  vals[val[:id]] = [val[:position]]
end
```

Now vals equals

```
{
  "GBMMV1800001" => [1],
  "GBMMV1800002" => [2],
  "GBMMV1800003" => [3]
}
```

Then I iterate through the second array, adding its positions.

```
h2.each do |val|
  # This will ignore ids that aren't present in h1
  next unless vals[val[:id]]
  vals[val[:id]].push val[:position]
end
```

Now I have all the data I need to calculate the diffs:

```
{
  "GBMMV1800001" => [1, 1],
  "GBMMV1800002" => [2, 3],
  "GBMMV1800003" => [3, 2]
}
```

To get the diffs I would use `transform_values` is available with ruby 2.4 or with active support. You could alternatively use `reduce` or `each_with_object` by the way.

```
diffs = vals.transform_values { |(pos1, pos2)| pos2 - pos1 }
```

This makes use of [destructuring](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html) in the block arguments.

Comment: You are abusing `each`, use `each_with_object({})` instead: `vals = h1.each_with_object({}) { |val|vals[val[:id]] = [val[:position]] }`.

Comment: @mudasobwa How is it abuse?

Comment: each is for iterating, not for reducing.

Comment: @mudasobwa Looks like iteration to me. Yours doesn't work, btw.

Comment: Ah, indeed I forgot an accumulator in block params. Iteration should not have side effects.

Comment: @mudasobwa "Iteration should not have side effects"? Says who? And what are the "side effects" there?

Comment: @mudasobwa To answer my own "says who" question: Apparently [*nobody*](https://www.google.com/search?q="Iteration+should+not+have+side+effects") other than you (that google search says *"No results found for "Iteration should not have side effects"."*)

Comment: @StefanPochmann I agree with @mudasobwa that each_with_object is better, it's not like a _the lord doth decree_ type prescription but I do consider it 'cleaner' to avoid side effects whenever possible. I used `each` just since it makes the code a little more digestable and my goal was to make OP understand the concept and not just give the most concise efficient code possible. Also keep in mind that my code doesn't give the same output structure as OP asked either.

Comment: @StefanPochmann the idea of avoiding side effects comes from functional programming. there are a lot of people who like to use those concepts and even languages which have almost no side effects.

Comment: @maxpleaner I still don't see what you guys mean with "side effect". Pure iteration is pointless. Doing something with the iterated elements is not a side effect but an effect.

Comment: @StefanPochmann you can think of the difference between `map`/`reduce` and `each`. With map or reduce you use the return value, with each you don't. `each_with_object` is more like `reduce` since you use the return value, Rather than modiying the `vals` hash, you would create a new hash with modified values. I would advise googling on the topic of "what is side effects free code"

Comment: @StefanPochmann Max Pleaner has basically already explained the difference, I’d add my ¢2. There are three types of “enumerating”: iteration, mapping, reducing. The former just walks over (e.g. to print values.) In FP iteration even _cannot_ change/collect anything. Mapping does 1-to-1 isomorphism. Reducing produces “anything” out of values. Of course, one might iterate with `loop.with_index { |_, i| break if i >= array.length }` or map with `array.reduce([]) { |acc, e| acc << e }`, but this is what I called abusing. The intent should be clear wherever possible. Here it’s reducing, not iter.

Comment: @mudasobwa Mmh, I think the intent *is* clear there. Did you actually look at that little piece of code and it wasn't clear to you what it's doing? I think it's *more* clear than your alternative, as it's significantly less code. And I'd say it's a little simpler, *as you proved by screwing yours up* :-P. Also, is printing not also a "side effect"?
 And the style guide does something similar as well (see [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#safe-because-unsafe) and [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#concat-strings)) and says nothing against it, I think.

Comment: ... @mudasobwa One more question: "Mapping does 1-to-1 isomorphism"? In what way? For example `map(&:odd?)` is clearly no isomorphism.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, indeed, it’s not an isomorphism, it’s just mapping. Still, I am positive you would agree that `a = []; [1,2,3].each { |e| a << e * e }` should be better written as mapping `a = [1,2,3].map { |e| e * e }`, and I am unsure why you defend reducing should be written as plain iteration. Also, declaring a local variable upfront and modifying it inside a loop breaks SRP and introduces a responsibility leak. Reducer is easily convertible to every language, while `each` cannot be ported to any functional language. When I see `each` I expect the iteration, not a cumbersome reducer.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, I find `map` much better there. I had actually done `h1.map { |h| [h[:id], h[:position]] }.to_h` here. And you're putting words in my mouth. I'm *not* saying it "should be written as plain iteration". I'm just saying I find that *ok*. You're the one saying it should be done one way and not another, not me. I'm btw not sure why you apparently think everybody needs to care about functional languages and that it's not easy to convert that `each` solution (I mean, except for your mistake you probably had no trouble transforming it to your beloved `each_with_object`, did you?).

Comment: @StefanPochmann well, ok :) My point is it’s always better to use reducers to reduce, mappers to map and iterators to iterate. That way people reading the code would expect the respective action based on the method chosen. Within this example it’s evident, but the block might have 10LOCs and many people won’t expect `each` to mutate something defined upfront. Maybe I have this feeling because I do not ruby anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick

```
def get_position_changes array0, array1
  array1.map.with_index do |hash1, index|
    new_hash = hash1.dup
    new_hash[:change] = array0.index {|hash0| hash0[:id] == hash1[:id]} - index
    new_hash
  end
end

first_array = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}, 
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"}
]

second_array = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"},
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}
]

p get_position_changes(first_array, second_array)

#=> [
#=>   {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001", :change=>0}
#=>   {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003", :change=>1}
#=>   {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002", :change=>-1}
#=> ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure you started with:

```
h1 = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}, 
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"}
]
h2 = [
  {:position=>1, :id=>"GBMMV1800001"}, 
  {:position=>2, :id=>"GBMMV1800003"},
  {:position=>3, :id=>"GBMMV1800002"}
]
```

is not appropriate. You should have instead started with structures like:

```
a1 = h1.map{|h| h[:id]} # => ["GBMMV1800001", "GBMMV1800002", "GBMMV1800003"]
a2 = h2.map{|h| h[:id]} # => ["GBMMV1800001", "GBMMV1800003", "GBMMV1800002"]
```

Given above,

```
b1 = a1.map.with_index(1).to_h
# => {"GBMMV1800001"=>1, "GBMMV1800002"=>2, "GBMMV1800003"=>3}
b2 = a2.map.with_index(1).to_h
# => {"GBMMV1800001"=>1, "GBMMV1800003"=>2, "GBMMV1800002"=>3}
b1.keys.map{|k| {id: k, position: b1[k], change: b2[k] - b1[k]}}
# => [
#      {:id=>"GBMMV1800001", :position=>1, :change=>0},
#      {:id=>"GBMMV1800002", :position=>2, :change=>1},
#      {:id=>"GBMMV1800003", :position=>3, :change=>-1}
#    ]
```

Comment: `change: b2[k] - b2[k]` should be read somehow else :) Also, you might consider returning what OP asked (changes against `h1`, yours is vice versa.)